# UART overrun error when attempting to write to transmit holding register (U0THR)

Tags: c, embedded, lpc, arm7

So, I have a terminal connected to TxD0 and RxD0 pins. Let's say that I just want to test whether writing to it works after all.

I wrote few functions to make UART be able to read and write chars and strings. Although if I try to run it in the simulator, it gives me an overrun error.

Here are the functions in uart.c file:

```
void uart0_write(unsigned char reg_data)
{
    while((U0LSR & (0x20)) != 0x20);/*wait until holding register is empty*/
    U0THR = (int) reg_data;/*write to holding register*/
}

void uart0_write_str(char str[])
{
    while(*str != '\0')/*check for EOF*/
    {
        uart0_write(*str);/*write a char*/
        str++;
    }
}
```

UART0 initialization function:

```
void uart0_init(void)
{
    PINSEL0 = 0x05; /*set pin P0.0 to TXD0 and P0.1 RxD0 (TXD0 - 01; RxD0 - 01; 0101 = 0x05)*/
    U0LCR = 0x83; /*set length for 8-bit word, set the stop bit, enable DLAB*/
    U0IER = (1<<0) | (1<<1);/*enable RBR and THR interrupts*/
    U0FCR = 0xC7; /*enable FIFO; reset Tx FIFO; set interrupt after 14 characters*/

    /*Baud rate configured to 9600 Baud (from lecture notes)*/
    U0DLL = 0x9D;
    U0DLM = 0x0;
    U0LCR = 0x03; /*8-bit character selection; disable DLAB*/
}
```

Exemplary use in main:

```
int main(void)
{
    char *introMsg;
    introMsg = "Hello World\n";

    systemInit();
    ADC_init();
    timer0_init();
    uart0_init();

    uart0_write_str(introMsg);

    /*or: */
    while(1)
    {
         uart0_write('c');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With these demonstrative code snippets the UART should work properly as I saw elsewhere on the web. 
But when attempting to run it, it doesn't print anything and the OE pops up.
What am I doing wrong? I'm only starting to dive into the depths of bare metal programming, so there might be some bug that I didn't notice.

I'd welcome any insights!

Stay home,

Jacob